# Upgraded to Debian 7.5; now 'memcpy@GLIBC_2.14' is undefined

Tags: c++, gcc, debian, glibc

A week ago I could compile and link my project (C++) with no issues.  However, after doing a `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` earlier this week, I can no longer link my program.

The error I get is like so:

```
Compiling CEF Client
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
Compiling cef_client
Build type: release-with-debug
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
Compiling ==> 'AttributeBinding.cpp'
Compiling ==> 'ClientApp.cpp'
Compiling ==> 'DuplicateAttributeException.cpp'
Compiling ==> 'DuplicateFunctionException.cpp'
Compiling ==> 'FunctionBinding.cpp'
Compiling ==> 'Main.cpp'
Compiling ==> 'ObjectBinding.cpp'
Compiling ==> 'Logger.cpp'
Linking program ==> 'cef3_client'
/home/jarrett/projects/icebreakers/glr/deps/boost/lib/libboost_log.so: undefined reference to `memcpy@GLIBC_2.14'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
scons: *** [build/cef3_client] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

Thing is, I built the boost log library on this same machine, and it worked fine until I did a `dist-upgrade`.

I had several other problems with include files before this, and I fixed it by reinstalling `gcc-4.7` and `gcc-4.7-base`.  I tried reinstalling `libc` as well, with: `sudo aptitude reinstall libc6 libc6-dbg libc6-dev`, but it didn't fix anything.

I also tried reinstalling a whole slew of packages that had `glib` in the name:

```
sudo aptitude reinstall gir1.2-glib-2.0 gir1.2-telepathyglib-0.12 gir1.2-upowerglib-1.0 glib-networking glib-networking-common glib-networking-services libavahi-glib1 libcglib-java libdbus-glib-1-2 libdbus-glib-1-dev libdbus-glib1.0-cil libgeocode-glib0 libghc-glib-dev libglib-perl libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-bin libglib2.0-cil libglib2.0-cil-dev libglib2.0-data libglib2.0-dev libglibmm-2.4-1c2a libglibmm-2.4-dev libjson-glib-1.0-0 libnm-glib-vpn1 libnm-glib4 libpackagekit-glib2-14 libpoppler-glib8 libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libsofia-sip-ua-glib3 libtelepathy-glib0 libupower-glib1
```

I also tried reinstalling `build-essentials`, `gcc`, and `g++`, to no effect.

Anyone have any ideas what is going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to recompile the Boost log library against the upgraded glibc. The .so file you have now was compiled against a previous version.

Comment: I was afraid of that.  I tried exporting the symbols from my `libc.so`, and I found `memcpy@@GLIBC_2.2.5`.  I'm curious - aren't these binaries supposed to be backwards compatible?  As in, not breaking ABI compatibility?

Comment: Their API will typically be backwards compatible (minus potentially deprecated functions), but the linker is looking for a specific version of the .so file. If you do an ldd on the binary, you'll see the symbol table specfically looks for a particular version.

Comment: Hmm..I think maybe my debian downgraded the glibc library from 2.14 to 2.13 - it's the only thing I can think of that would cause an ABI break.  Oh well, I guess I'll just have to recompile :)  Thanks @CDahn